# add serial count to each group pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple problem but haven't been able to fix it.

I have a simple table such as:

```
group1 
a
a
a
b
b
b
c
c
```

I can add a count to the column with:

```
df['count'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)
```

I have tried to alter this with groupby functions but can't manage to stop the count and restart per group such as:

```
group1 count
a 1
a 2
a 3
b 1
b 2
b 3
c 1
c 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html). If you want to start from `1` you could add it:

```
In [16]: df['count'] = df.groupby('group1').cumcount()+1

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
  group1  count
0      a      1
1      a      2
2      a      3
3      b      1
4      b      2
5      b      3
6      c      1
7      c      2
```